# Trying to run 'alchemy' on Mac OS X and this is the error I get

Tags: macos, mac, development

Trying to install alchemy from http://al.chemy.org
It is an application for artists. But apparently it isn't running on my machine. As soon as I try to run this, it creates an error 'No module found'. Now I don't know where the modules need to be installed or copy pasted. So anybody here could tell me where the folder is?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Linux downloadable version which comes with two files, "Alchemy" and "AlchemyOpenGL". Open one of these files with Terminal, that will prompt the app to launch on its own. Note that you may have to install Java software for Alchemy to work on your current OSX, just as for pre CC versions of Adobe Illustrator. You can download the latest version of Java for OS X directly from Oracle's website. Works on Sierra and High Sierra.

Comment: I’m happy to report that this solution still works with MacOS Big Sur.

Answer (score -1):

Wasted a morning trying to fix this.  Then it dawned on me that of course OSX is Linux, so I installed the Linux version and it worked.